# Consumir Json e direcionar para um banco de dados usando C#

Tags: c#, json

Estou tendo dificuldades em consumir um retorno [json](/questions/tagged/json) e converter-lo em objeto para então gravar no banco de dados, as minhas variáveis retornam sempre "null", já tentei várias formas e sempre fico barrado neste retorno. Segue parte do código:

1) Conteúdo Json:

```
{  
  "list":[  
    {  
      "Pedido":"1234",
      "Data":"2018-05-21",
      "Cliente":"Jose Teste",
      "Itens":[  
        {  
          "Codigo":"1",
          "Quantidade":1,
          "ItemNome":"Tomada trifasica Elgin",
          "Preco":25.50
        }
      ],
      "Total":25.50,
      "FormaDePagamento":"cheque",
    }
  ]
}
```

---

2) Classe modelo no C#:

```
namespace ApiTeste.Models
{
    public class Pedidos
    {
        public Pedido[] list { get; set; }
        //public List<Pedido> pedido { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pedido
    {
        public string NumPedido { get; set; }
        public string Data { get; set; }
        public string Cliente { get; set; }
        public Iten[] Itens { get; set; }
        public float Total { get; set; }
        public string FormaDePagamento { get; set; }
    }

    public class Iten
    {
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public int Quantidade { get; set; }
        public string ItemNome { get; set; }
        public float Preco { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

3) Parte do método que retorna o Json para direcionar para o objeto:

```
using (HttpWebResponse retornoServJson = (HttpWebResponse)requisicaoWeb.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream retornoServJson = retornoJson.GetResponseStream())
    {                   
        using (StreamReader retornoReaderJson = new StreamReader(retornoServJson))
        {
            var response = retornoReader.ReadToEnd();
            Pedido pedido = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Pedido>(response);  //aqui o objeto retorna null
            string teste = pedido.NumPedido; //aqui o objeto retorna null
            string teste2 = pedido.Data; //aqui o objeto retorna null
        }
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 1):

A Classe Pedido o Atributo `NumPedido` deve ser `Pedido`.

```
namespace ApiTeste.Models
{
public class Pedidos
{
    public Pedido[] list { get; set; }
    //public List<Pedido> pedido { get; set; }
}

public class Pedido
{
    public string NumPedido { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string Cliente { get; set; }
    public Iten[] Itens { get; set; }
    public float Total { get; set; }
    public string FormaDePagamento { get; set; }
}

public class Iten
{
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public int Quantidade { get; set; }
    public string ItemNome { get; set; }
    public float Preco { get; set; }
}
}
```

---

Sobre a conversão de Json para o Objeto Pedidos.

Utilizaria o [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/)

```
using (HttpWebResponse retornoServJson = (HttpWebResponse)requisicaoWeb.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream retornoServJson = retornoJson.GetResponseStream())
    {                   
        using (StreamReader retornoReaderJson = new StreamReader(retornoServJson))
        {
            var response = retornoReader.ReadToEnd();
            Pedido pedido = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Pedido>(response);
            string teste = pedido.NumPedido; //aqui o objeto retorna null
            string teste2 = pedido.Data; //aqui o objeto retorna null
        }
    }
}
```

O `response` deve ser String.

Comment: Elivelton, obrigado pela postagem, porém continua retornando "null", quando eu rodo em modo debug eu vejo que os steps não passam pela classe "Pedido", acredito que minha implementação esta errada antes desse passo, vou rever. Se tiver uma dica agradeço. Abraços.

Answer (score 0):

Passei alguns dias testando diversas soluções e cheguei nesta solução, logo compartilho:

```
using (StreamReader retornoReaderJson = new StreamReader(retornoServJson))
{
    Global.retorno = (retornoReaderJson.ReadToEnd());

    string JSON = @Global.retorno;
    JObject pedido = JObject.Parse(JSON);

    IList<JToken> equipamentos = pedido["list"].Children().ToList();
    foreach (JToken equip in equipamentos)
    {
        IList<JToken> comandos = equip.Children().ToList();
        foreach (JToken cmd in comandos)
        {
            //Fica em looping passando dadopor dado
            dadoDaPedido = (cmd.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```